# Retrieving from Map

Tags: java, collections

I have a map like below:-

```
HashMap<String, Set<String>> mapList;
```

I'm retrieving the data like below:-

```
mapList.forEach((k, v) -> {
    System.out.println("URL" + k);
    Set<String> s = mapList.get(k);
    s.forEach(e -> {
        System.out.print(e);
    });
});
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You don't need to do `mapList.get(k);`. You already have the value in `v`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a method reference for the second `forEach`, and you are doing an unnecessary `mapList.get` - you already have the value.

```
forEach((k, v) -> {
    System.out.println("URL" + k);
    v.forEach(System.out::print);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are looking for:

```
mapList.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("URL " + k + ", values : " + v)));
```

which will output the following:

> URL http://url1, values: [a, b] 
>   URL http://url2, values: [c, d]

Comment: It's not the same, but it's close

Comment: The reason it's not the same is because it's pointless to print all the elements of a collection without a delimiter. It makes any sense only for the case where the key is the base URL and then the set contains all the get parameter definitions, like : `k = http://example.com?` and `v = [user=dbl, app=so, thread=52760941]` but then the **ampersand** should be added dynamically.

Comment: Like : `mapList.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("URL: " + k + "?" + v.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("&"))));` -> URL: *http://example.com?app=so&thread=52760941&user=dbl*